# Generate JSON without slashes using PHP & MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, json

i want to generate JSON values **exactly** like this one here

```
{
    "feed": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "National Geographic Channel",
            "image": "http://api.androidhive.info/feed/img/cosmos.jpg",
            "status": "\"Science is a beautiful and emotional human endeavor,\" says Brannon Braga, executive producer and director. \"And Cosmos is all about making science an experience.\"",
            "profilePic": "http://api.androidhive.info/feed/img/nat.jpg",
            "timeStamp": "1403375851930",
            "url": null
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "name": "TIME",
            "image": "http://api.androidhive.info/feed/img/time_best.jpg",
            "status": "30 years of Cirque du Soleil's best photos",
            "profilePic": "http://api.androidhive.info/feed/img/time.png",
            "timeStamp": "1403375851930",
            "url": "http://ti.me/1qW8MLB"
        }
    ]
}
```

and every time i try to do such a thing i end up with this output

```
{
    "feed": [{
        "id": "1",
        "name": "National Geographic Channel",
        "image": "http:\/\/api.androidhive.info\/feed\/img\/cosmos.jpg",
        "status": "Science is a beautiful and emotional human endeavor",
        "profilePic": "http:\/\/api.androidhive.info\/feed\/img\/nat.jpg",
        "timeStamp": "1403375851930",
        "url": "null"
    }, {
        "id": "2",
        "name": "National Geographic Channel",
        "image": "http:\/\/api.androidhive.info\/feed\/img\/cosmos.jpg",
        "status": "Science is a beautiful and emotional human endeavor",
        "profilePic": "http:\/\/api.androidhive.info\/feed\/img\/nat.jpg",
        "timeStamp": "1403375851930",
        "url": "null"
    }]
}
```

look at the ID in the first json, and the URLs 
i want my json to be exactly like the first one

my php code :

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="application/json; charset=utf-8 ">
<?php

include "../funcs/db.php";
$SelectPosts = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM usf_mobile");
$rows = array();
   while($r = mysql_fetch_assoc($SelectPosts)) {
     $rows['feed'][] = $r;
   }

 print json_encode($rows);

?>
```

i tried a LOT of solutions here on **stackoverflow** and i didn't find any one who could be close to my problem.

Comment: Type cast id value in to int like $id = (int)$id;

Comment: First of all why it should be **exactly** like this?

Comment: You need to look at adding options to the encode http://php.net/manual/en/json.constants.php that will at least help with the URLS using JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES

Comment: @u_mulder because this is the only way the JSON worked on my android app :(

Comment: If you have php 5.4+ you can use `JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES` and `JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK` to get the results you want.

Comment: @FunkDoc could you give me an example please

Comment: @JonathanKuhn Example please im beginner in JSON

Comment: `json_encode($array, JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES | JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK)`. You can find all of this on the manual page for [json_encode](http://www.php.net/json_encode).

Comment: [`mysql_` is deprecated](http://php.net/manual/de/migration55.deprecated.php) by the way.

Comment: @JonathanKuhn Awesome, Thank you worked :) please post as answer to rate UP

Comment: @KeVin i know, but we are talking about JSON here :)

Comment: Still something you should fix.

Comment: @KeVin i'll worry about that later

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cast the ID value to integer using `(int)`, and escape the URL slashes with `JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES`;

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="application/json; charset=utf-8 ">
<?php

include "../funcs/db.php";
$SelectPosts = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM usf_mobile");
$rows = array();
   while($r = mysql_fetch_assoc($SelectPosts)) {
     $r['id'] = (int)$r['id'];
     $rows['feed'][] = $r;
   }

 print json_encode($rows,JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES);

?>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank You Awesome, will make the correct answer in 5 min :)

Comment: one more thing, did you see the URL ? it says null in the first JSON not "null" as my json, how do i make it the same also ?

Comment: Try `if(!$r['url'] == "null") unset($r['url']);`. Not 100% on that, but give it a go.

Comment: You can assign the constant `NULL` instead. `if(!$r['url'] == "null") $r['url'] = NULL;` or it might be (depending on the database output) `if(!$r['url']) $r['url'] = NULL;`.

Answer (score 3):

If you have php 5.4+ you can use `JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES` and `JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK` to get the results you want.

```
json_encode($array, JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES | JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK)
```

You can find all of this on the manual page for [json_encode](http://www.php.net/json_encode).

Answer (score 2):

You are using `mysql_query()` (which you shouldn't be doing since it is deprecated).  The problem with this is that you have no way to bind columns to value types (string, integer, etc.).  Everything is being returned as a string.

I would suggest using `mysqli` or `PDO` where you can specify column types when binding to them.  Without this, you will need to manually cast your values before encoding to JSON.

Comment: thx for the note pro, BUT im here asking about JSON and NOT about MySql :)

Comment: @YoussefAlSubaihi Yes, but your problem lies specifically in the fact that when reading data out of MySQL with `mysql_query()` ALL values are treated as string. You need to understand this, all it is much yes fragile to actually build your data structure as intended and serialize it (to JSON in this case) than it is to try to massage the data during the serialization process as has been suggested in some of the other answers.

Comment: so what you are saying is if i use mysqli or pdo, i won't be needed to use JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES ? or ``(int)$r['id'];`` ?

Comment: @YoussefAlSubaihi With regards to your slashes, I don;t understand WHY you would want to escape them.  `\/` is generally understood escape sequence and should be handle easily when the client deserialiazes the JSON string.  You are potentially now going to force the client to have to understand that you have serialized your JSON in a non-standard fashion.  WIth using mysqli or PDO, you have the ability to explicityl define data types in the response, so if you DB table has an integer column, you can get integer value in PHP, same with nulls.

Comment: Yes BUT im using this JSON with Android app and using it with Volly library and it's cannot be read using volly if it has slashes

Answer (score 2):

Try following example if you are using PHP 5.4+

```
 $rows = json_encode($rows,JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK | JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES | JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```

For lower versions you can type cast values in your array to get desired result.